# ColorPicker bind color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem and i dont know how to deal with it: i have a ColorPicker and a button to reset back to default color, look like this:

```
<div id="headercolor2"></div>
<button type="button" onlcick="resetColor()">Reset</button>

<script>
 $('#headercolor2').ColorPicker({
            color: '#000000',
            onShow: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            },
            onHide: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            },
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) 
            }
        });
</script>
```

I want to reset back to my default color if i click on the reset button. But i dont know how to do it. I have searched for the document but i could not find it. What should i do inside resetColor()? thank you.

Comment: Which library is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ library. If so, your function should look like:

```
function resetColor() {
    $('#headercolor2').ColorPickerSetColor('#ff0000');
}
```

There was an example of this right on the "Implement" tab on the site above. The documentation states that the default color is `#ff0000`.